# Mismatched input end of line without line continuation expecting ) - pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have an error in my code that does not let me add the indicator to the chart, the following message appears in the console '

```
Error at 20:22 Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')'
```

this problem is in this specific part Of code:

```
myLabel := label.new(
    x=bar_index,
    y=high,
    text="NPL: " + tostring(npl),
    yloc=yloc.abovebar,
    color=color.green,
    textcolor=color.white,
    style=label.style_label_left
)
```

I will also attach an image so that you understand the problem in depth:

[issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef1xg.png)

the complete code below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("NPL Calculator v3", overlay=false)

// Inputs
percent = input.float(title="Percentage", defval=20.0, step=0.01) / 100
leverage = input.float(title="Leverage", defval=10.0, step=0.01)
money = input.float(title="Money", defval=100.0, step=0.01)

// Calculations
npl = money * percent * leverage

// Plots
plot(npl, title="NPL", color=color.blue, style=plot.style_line)

// Labels
var label myLabel = na
if not na(myLabel)
    label.delete(myLabel)

myLabel := label.new(
    x=bar_index,
    y=high,
    text="NPL: " + tostring(npl),
    yloc=yloc.abovebar,
    color=color.green,
    textcolor=color.white,
    style=label.style_label_left
)

// Alert
alertcondition(npl > 0, title="NPL Alert", message="NPL: " + tostring(npl))

// Backtesting
strategy.entry("NPL Buy", strategy.long, when=npl > 0)
strategy.close("NPL Buy", when=npl <= 0)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

fix this part of the code mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pinescript the indentation for local block is 4 spaces and you musn't use it elsewhere.
You should indent you line.new code with 3 spaces (or 2, or 5, but not with 4 spaces), like this :

```
myLabel := label.new(
   x=bar_index, 
   y=high, 
   text="NPL: " + str.tostring(npl), 
   yloc=yloc.abovebar, 
   color=color.green, 
   textcolor=color.white, 
   style=label.style_label_left)
```

NB : There are other error in your code, do not hesitate to ask a new question with your new code if you can't solve them.

Comment: Thank you so much! and i saw the other error and i fixed it, thanks for your help :D